# Compare bool and float to determine plot (pine script v5)

Tags: boolean, pine-script

You folks helped me with another part of this script and I'm making good progress. However, I'm stuck again.

I added a code to produce a dynamic overbought/oversold line on the indicator. That part works great.  Now, I'm wanting to add a plotshape when conditions are met to signal long or short.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to compare a bool variable and a float variable.  The dynamic OB/OS lines are floats. The crossover lines are bool.

What I want is for the (green/long) shape to plot when a crossover happens below the dynamic oversold line and the (red/short) shape to plot when the crossunder happens above the dynamic overbought line.

I've tried all kinds of things (var, loop with "while" using sb value as a trigger). I either break the code or I get every crossover plotted. Here is what I have that is stable. I took all my junk that didn't work out:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © HammerGeek

//@version=5
indicator('Impulse MACD [HammerGeek - LazyBear]', shorttitle='IMACD_HG_LB', overlay=false)
lengthMA = input(34)
lengthSignal = input(9)
//OverBought = input.float(0.1)
//OverSold = input.float(-0.1)


calc_smma(src, len) =>
    smma = 0.0
    sma_1 = ta.sma(src, len)
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma_1 : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len
    smma

calc_zlema(src, length) =>
    ema1 = ta.ema(src, length)
    ema2 = ta.ema(ema1, length)
    d = ema1 - ema2
    ema1 + d

src = hlc3
hi = calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo = calc_smma(low, lengthMA)
mi = calc_zlema(src, lengthMA)

md = mi > hi ? mi - hi : mi < lo ? mi - lo : 0
sb = ta.sma(md, lengthSignal)
sh = md - sb
mda = ta.sma(md, lengthSignal)
OverBoughtLine = ta.highest(sb * 0.5, lengthMA*100)
OverSoldLine = ta.lowest(sb * 0.5, lengthSignal*100)
shsbCrossOver = ta.crossover(md, sb)
shsbCrossUnder = ta.crossunder(md, sb)

//mdc = src > mi ? src > hi ? color.lime : color.green : src < lo ? color.red : color.orange
mdc = color.green
plot(0, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=1, title='MidLine')
plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title='ImpulseMACD', style=plot.style_line)
plot(sh, color=color.rgb(122, 5, 168, 40), linewidth=2, title='ImpulseHisto', style=plot.style_area)
plot(sb, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255, transp = 40), linewidth=2, title='ImpulseMACDCDSignal')
plot(OverBoughtLine, color=color.new(#f3e032, 0), linewidth=1, title = 'Overbought Line')
plot(OverSoldLine, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), linewidth=1, title = 'Oversold Line')
plotshape(shsbCrossOver, "LONG", shape.triangleup, location.bottom, color.new(color.green, 0))
plotshape(shsbCrossUnder, "SHORT", shape.triangledown, location.top, color.new(#cd0808, 0))

//ebc = input(false, title='Enable bar colors')
//barcolor(ebc ? mdc : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare a `bool` with a `float`. It doesn't make any sense and it is not legal in `pinescript`.

> What I want is for the (green/long) shape to plot when a crossover
> happens below the dynamic oversold line and the (red/short) shape to
> plot when the crossunder happens above the dynamic overbought line.

You want to check if the values you use in that `crossover` is under your dynamic oversold line at the time of crossover.

```
OverSoldLine = ta.lowest(sb * 0.5, lengthSignal*100)
shsbCrossOver = ta.crossover(md, sb)
is_good = shsbCrossOver and (md < OverSoldLine) and (sb < OverSoldLine)
```